# Automatically include N latest kernel versions in GRUB / GRUB2 menu on kernel upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, boot, linux-kernel, grub2

What I like about Ubuntu is that the GRUB menu always allows me to pick the latest (default) or second-latest (etc.) kernel version at boot time.

In Arch Linux, I can't do that by default. The only options are normal and fallback images, and both boot the latest kernel. How can I achieve the Ubuntu-like behavior in Arch? I use Grub and Grub2, but I guess that I wouldn't have to configure the bootloader much. It will probably include the images it finds in `/boot` in the menu automatically. I can be wrong, though.

So, what I need, from most to least important, is:

1. That the new kernel image created by `mkinitcpio` during the upgrade doesn't overwrite the previous one;
2. That the latest kernel is present in the bootloader menu as default option;
3. That very old versions are excluded from the menu or hidden into "older version" menu item *(not that important)*.

How would one go about this? Should I look into `mkinitcpio` config or maybe `pacman` config? I've actually tried looking at configuration files for both, no ideas so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this bug:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/16702#comment80122

And this blogpost:
http://losinggeneration.homelinux.org/2009/10/16/why-arch-linuxs-kernel-upgrades-suck/

So far I haven't found a good solution, but I will update if I do.

One thing to keep in mind beyond grub, the kernel, and initrd is /usr/lib/modules/. When the linux package updates the old package deletes it's folders in /usr/lib/modules/ and the new kernel adds its new modules. If you want both kernels working, you're going to want both sets of modules. And /usr/src/ contains the kernel headers (needed to build new modules, such as the nvidia drivers), so you'll probably want to keep those, too.

The steps I guess would be something like:
1. Detect linux package is going to be upgraded.
2. Backup what it's going to delete on uninstall (/usr/src/$(uname -r), /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r), /boot/{vmlinuz-linux,initramfs-linux.img,initramfs-linux-fallback.img})
3. Let pacman do its upgrade
4. Restore everything in 2 (probably giving a new name to the stuff in /boot
5. Edit grub or whatever.

Alternate steps (somewhat less good)
 1. Let pacman update
 2. Detect kernel was updated
 3. from /var/cache/packman/pkg/linux-${previous_version}-pkg.tar.xz extract /usr/src/, /usr/lib/{modules,extramodules}, and /boot/vmlinuz (renaming the one in /boot, obviously)
 4. run mkinitcpio with the -k option to build the old init
 5. Edit grub or whatever

In this alternate method, you loose your 3rd party modules (virtual box, ATI/Nvidia, etc), but it might be something you could run from cron and automagically detect kernel updates have occured.

Comment: Thanks for the links, this is a very good read. I wonder how long it will take before the problem is solved as suggested in the linked comment. Long enough, it seems to me. The answer is very helpful, though, thanks again.

Comment: In /etc/pacman.conf, you can ignore "linux". This turns the kernel (and dependencies like modules) into manual installs. "Yaourt" is not happy about this, though. :-/

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages describes using your local package cache to re-install old packages. That could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I remember the newest kernel is always the first one in the /boot/grub/grub.conf file. To automatically load the first entry you need to put the following two lines at the top of grub.conf

```
default         0
timeout         1
```

The grub loader waits the `timeout` time in seconds. And `default` is the x kernel in the list of kernels.

regarding `mkinitcpio`: I don't think there is an easy way. But I thought always the last and the current kernel will be available at boot time and the newest kernel is always at postition 0 in the grub.conf.

Comment: No, the previous kernel is not available by default, unfortunately.